# Convert video files for home IIS server

Tags: video-streaming

I am finally learning to set up an IIS server (personal use only) and I thought it would be cool to have some videos on it for me to watch when I am away from home. Since I'm usually on 3G (iPhone) or work wifi, I'd like to convert them to an optimal format that will stream fast. The video files are mostly avi and mp4 (from 30 minutes to 2 hours in length). What would be an easy and fast way to go about doing this? Thanks.

**Edit**
I am using Windows 7. There are many files but most of them say "XVID", "H.264/MPEG-4 AVC", MPEG4, DivX. I also have many DVD ISOs (they contain vob and ifo files) that I'd like to convert.

The speed is not as fast as my home internet connection but the bandwidth is unlimited.

Comment: What operating system are you using to convert the files?

Comment: If they're AVI and MP4 files, what *codec* is inside? Can you use MediaInfo to check that? Do you have any bandwidth restrictions (e.g. because you're only connecting via 3G, etc)?

Comment: Edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

3gp is a common standard of compressing video for streaming video to mobile devices. You can use ffmpeg to convert the files to 3gp, you can also play with video size and bit rate to find a good format for your purposes. For streaming on IIS you can use Smooth Streaming.